# 2 Divs side by side => screen minimze => 1 under another one

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs and have already aligned them side by side. If I minimize my screen (for example, if screen width is 400px), I want the DIVs to be aligned one under another one.

How can I do that? Thanks.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#section1 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#section2 {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="section1">
    Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1
  </div>
  <div id="section2">
    Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1/ Section 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into media queries

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use media query

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #section1, #section2 {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You will want to generate a media query for max-width: 400px. The CSS would look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #parent {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nk0r9sLt/2/).